# stroke imagebrush windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, imagebrush

I am using imagebrush as stroke when i draw polyline.

```
var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/br1.png"));
        img = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageBrush()
        {
            ImageSource = bitmapImage,
            Stretch = Stretch.None,
        };
```

And create polyline:

```
this._polyline = new Polyline() { 
            StrokeThickness = 23,                
              Stroke = img,                  

        };
```

But image stretch when i draw polyline in canvas. I can't repeat imagebrush, can you help me?